# ROS Lunar on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone successfully run ROS Lunar on Ubuntu 17.10?  If so, I'd be grateful for instructions on how to do it. Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277021/ros-lunar-on-ubuntu-17.10?/) by [peebz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32170/peebz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-01**:
Related questions: #q262187 (discusses Kinetic on 17.04, but conceptually the same), #q274615.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Officially this is not supported, so there are no binary packages available (but you are probably already aware of this, see also [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019)).

A source install could be possible, but is not guaranteed to work, as dependencies may have changed between Zesty and Artful. As for instructions: see [wiki/lunar/Installation/Source](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Source) (replace occurences of `zesty` in commands with `artful` where needed).

---

Edit: as I was curious myself, I just did this in an Artful Docker container. I basically followed the Lunar source instructions (so for 17.04), but had to make some minor changes to some commands.

As `rosdep` doesn't have any `artful` entries yet, pretend it's really `zesty` (under *Resolving dependencies*) (added the `--skip-keys` to avoid trying to reinstall `rosdep` again):

```
rosdep install --from-paths src -i --rosdistro=lunar --os ubuntu:zesty -y --skip-keys="python-rosdep"
```

To be able to install `shiboken2` and related pkgs, add the OSRF repositories following [the instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list) (`artful` appears to be missing `dirmngr`, which made `apt-key` fail, so install it `dirmngr` with `apt` (see also #q275824 and #q264654)).

After that I could follow the regular instructions again.

The build is still running, so I don't know whether it works, but it would seem to at least compile for now.

---

Edit2: build just finished, no really significant problems afaict. `roscore` started, but haven't tested anything else.

---

Edit3: after building, you probably want to add `export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=ubuntu:17.04:zesty` to your `.bashrc` (or similar file). At least until `rosdep` gets its rules updated for `artful`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peebz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32170/peebz/) on 2017-12-01**:
Many thanks for your answer and for testing it out.  I will give it a go.  It will give me an excuse to finally do something with Docker too.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-01**:
Dockerfile that worked for me: [gist](https://gist.github.com/gavanderhoorn/28062c9ba78eed6cb098569a5b886896).

**Comment by [nile649](https://answers.ros.org/users/33407/nile649/) on 2018-01-23**:
Hey, Hi it is giving me opencv error, how can I exclude opencv from make, it is really urgent

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
This is a regular "ROS from source" installation - just on an unsupported OS - so excluding packages would be done the same way as always.

**Comment by [nile649](https://answers.ros.org/users/33407/nile649/) on 2018-01-24**:
I was able to build but the final error before exit is  on this lines
COPY ./ros_entrypoint.sh \

ENTRYPOINT ["/ros_entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
`ros_entrypoint.sh` is standard file in all ROS Docker images, see [osrf/docker_images/ros/indigo/ubuntu/trusty/ros-core/ros_entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/5399f380af0a7735405a4b6a07c6c40b867563bd/ros/indigo/ubuntu/trusty/ros-core/ros_entrypoint.sh).

**Comment by [nile649](https://answers.ros.org/users/33407/nile649/) on 2018-01-24**:
Thanks, will have a look